# how to match date format condition using mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to compare the date fields in my form.

```
$mindate=$_POST['mindate'];
$maxdate =$_POST['maxdate'];



select min(date_format(b.start_date,'%d-%m- 
%Y'))as time_stamp  from omr_verification a 
,valuation_regular b 
where  date_format(b.start_date,'%Y-%m-%d') 
 >= '".$mindate."'
and date_format(b.end_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <= 
'".$maxdate."'
```

it gives null values. how to match the condition

Comment: Why you are not choose your table column structure as date it will make auto (Y-m-d) Formate then you can easily handle this every query either you will get More complex way to do that

Comment: start_date timestamp

Comment: end_date timestamp

Comment: in my table values are stored as 2018-11-27 00:00:00

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks with that code, you should ***ALWAYS*** use prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's DATE() function to obtain only the date part of your TIMESTAMP:

MySQL will implicitly add a time of 00:00:00 to the date literals, but you can include them explicitly if so preferred.

```
$mindate=$_POST['mindate'];
$maxdate =$_POST['maxdate'];


    select min(date(b.start_date))as time_stamp  from omr_verification a,valuation_regular b where  date(b.start_date) >= '".$mindate."' and date(b.end_date) <= '".$maxdate."'
```

**Hope this Will help you**

Comment: select min(date(b.start_date))as time_stamp  from omr_verification a,valuation_regular b where  date(b.start_date) >= '2018-11-27' and date(b.end_date) <= '2018-11-27'

Comment: null value only displayed

Comment: Ok trying to be used b.start_date instead of min(datee(b.start_date)) and let me know what will return . We can shortout this if we get data

Comment: min(date) not datee dear

Comment: select min(date(start_date))as time_stamp  from regular  it gives     2018-11-27

Comment: select min(date(b.start_date))as time_stamp from  valuation_regular b where date(b.start_date) >= '2018-11-27' and date(b.end_date) <= '2018-11-27'

why you want to use omr_verification a . There you nothing to select or check condition from this table

Comment: i remove the table after no result.

Comment: Above query what result did you getting?

Comment: null result only displayed

Comment: ok dear please remove the b. from select and from conditions 

select min(date(start_date)) as time_stamp from valuation_regular where date(start_date) >= '2018-11-27' and date(end_date) <= '2018-11-27'

Comment: select min(date(start_date))as time_stamp from valuation_regular where date(start_date) >= '2018-11-27' and date(end_date) <= '2018-11-27'

Comment: it also gives null

Comment: It should return data if you have record within this date

Comment: i have 2018-11-27 09:46:00 in my table

Comment: can you please send me the database records